# Media Recorder In Android - File Formats

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

A part of my android app uses [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) to capture voice input through the phone's mic.
The problem I am facing is with the format.
**What AudioEncoder and MediaFormat to use to play the audio file on the computer? What should be the extension of the file?**
If I use the following

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

and save the file as mp4, I am able to hear it on my phone. But when I connect my phone to the laptop and play it by navigating in my laptop, it does not play at all.

Also, eventually I want a .wav format file. I read here that Android doesn't support .wav or .mp3 so would have to use a 3rd party audio convertor. Is there any other way to capture .wav codec format audio file from android device? Can anyone help me out?? thanks!! :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use audio record class to record audio files. AudioRecord records the files in raw format, then you can convert those files to wav format. You can find examples to convert raw data to wav.

https://github.com/adsl54010/AudioRecord

Comment: The link is dead. Please do not post link-only answers. Better embed essential parts of the content in your answer.